# Ansible - How to remove a docker container after start?

Tags: docker, ansible

Below is the shell command we use to launch a docker container:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker container run --rm -it  \
        -e name1=value1 -e name2=value2 -e name3=value3 \
        1111112222.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteam/app-deploy:v.1
```

---

where we use `--rm` & `--it` option.

Currently I wrote the above code logic in ansible using `docker_container` module as:

```
- name: Create a data container
  docker_container:
    name: mydeploycontainer
    image: 1111112222.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteam/app-deploy:v.1
    env:
      name1: "value1"
      name2: "value2"
      name3: "value3"
```

---

How to start the container using ansible module with `--rm` & `--it` mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `auto_remove: yes`, `tty: yes`, and I believe `interactive: yes`, but that may be wrong, I'm just guessing based on a brief Google.

Credit where credit is due for the first half of my answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298664/way-to-set-rm-flag-for-ansible-docker-module

Look through the options here if you ever need to set a flag and see if any match:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html

Comment: @JeffSchaller  This is part of the jenkins pipeline.. where jenkins triggers this ansible module very frequently...so am not sure, how `tty:yes` impacts?

Comment: The `-it` flag stands for interactive and tty, i.e. it creates an interactive pseudoterminal for you, so you need to specify both in the module if you want to keep that flag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368411/what-is-docker-run-it-flag

Comment: I see this error: `"Unsupported parameters for (docker_container) module: auto_remove.`

Comment: What version of Ansible are you running? It was added in 2.4.

Comment: Tower is running Ansible 2.3.1.0 What is the alternative for 2.3?

Comment: Shell command I guess? I'd just update Tower if you're able to, you're five versions behind right now and there have been quite a few helpful updates since then, but if you're restricted in that regard you're stuck with using a shell command, sorry. Make sure to leave a comment to switch to the module once Tower is updated to version >=2.4, maybe even leave in your task that uses the module in a comment.

Comment: Using `command` module in ansible tower: `command: "docker container run --rm -it -e APP={{app}} -e BRANCH_NAME={{b}} -e BUILD={{buildnum}} 11112222333.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteam/deploy:v.1”` I get error: `the input device is not a TTY`

Comment: No idea, I don't know Docker at all really so I'm out of my depth at this point, have you tested this command on an actual system yet? Assuming you have, the only difference I can spot is you have `$blah/app-deploy:v.1` in your original question and `$blah/deploy:v.1` in the command you just commented. If that doesn't fix it, would removing the `-it` flag kill the functionality you need?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099116/error-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty